# Oracle - Get latest timestamp updated rows for multiple criteria from audit table

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, rank

We've an audit table that tracks of the changes of the different tables along with the column_names, user, timestamp, oldvalue and the newvalue based on the Invoicenumber. I need to retrieve latest audit data (last timestamp) across a specific set of tables and specific set of columns for a particular invoicenumber.

| Invoice_Number | Table_Name | Column_Name | Timestamp | User | Old_Value | New_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | A | 1 | 10-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | B | 1 | 11-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | A | 2 | 11-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 114 | B | 1 | 12-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | A | 2 | 13-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 122 | B | 2 | 13-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 122 | A | 5 | 13-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | A | 2 | 15-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 114 | B | 3 | 16-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | B | 2 | 18-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 112 | A | 1 | 10-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 142 | B | 1 | 11-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 102 | A | 2 | 11-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 184 | B | 1 | 12-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 142 | D | 2 | 13-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
| 118 | C | 2 | 18-OCT-2021 12.00.00.111111 | User1 | 7 | 6 |

Now I need to get the last updated records for Invoice number 112 with changes made in (Table A & Column 1, 2) and changes made in (Table B & column 1,2).

I tried using rank but not sure how to expand it beyond one column.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, the results of that try,  and the exact expected output of the above data.  Hint see [MAX()](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/max.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  invoice_number = 112
  AND    table_name IN ('A', 'B')
  AND    column_name IN (1, 2)
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY /*invoice_number,*/ table_name, column_name
  ORDER     BY timestamp DESC
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (^ last_row)
  DEFINE  last_row AS 1 = 1
)
```

In earlier versions, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY /*invoice_number,*/ table_name, column_name
           ORDER     BY timestamp DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  invoice_number = 112
  AND    table_name IN ('A', 'B')
  AND    column_name IN (1, 2)
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

*Note: since you only have a single `invoice_number` you don't need to include it in the `PARTITION BY` clause; however, if you had multiple `invoice_number`s then you would want to.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Invoice_Number, Table_Name, Column_Name, Timestamp, "USER", Old_Value, New_Value) AS
SELECT 112, 'A', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-10 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'B', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-11 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'A', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-11 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 114, 'B', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-12 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'A', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-13 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 'B', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-13 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 'A', 5, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-13 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'A', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-15 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 114, 'B', 3, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-16 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'B', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-18 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'A', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-10 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 142, 'B', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-11 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'A', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-11 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 184, 'B', 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-12 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 142, 'D', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-13 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 118, 'C', 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-18 12:00:00.111111', 'User1', 7, 6 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | TIMESTAMP | INVOICE_NUMBER | USER | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | 10-OCT-21 12.00.00.111111000 | 112 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
> | A | 2 | 15-OCT-21 12.00.00.111111000 | 112 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
> | B | 1 | 11-OCT-21 12.00.00.111111000 | 112 | User1 | 7 | 6 |
> | B | 2 | 18-OCT-21 12.00.00.111111000 | 112 | User1 | 7 | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b4d6490d30da64ad6863e7b18bf4250)*

Comment: Thanks @mt0. The later query worked